# Different Parallel Module in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

These days I have to deal with extremely large log data (700GB after compressed as 7z), the performance issue is critical. Considering the environment i was working (8-Cores), I was thinking leveraging parallel programming to achieve better performance. 
Currently I was using the built-in multiprocessing library, the performance improved but i wanted even better. I've heard there are many other parallel programming library for python, such as pp.

So my question is what is the differenece between those modules? Is there one better than the others?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any particular reason you wouldn't get the best performance out of the multiprocessing library.  Is there some reason you think another strategy would perform better?  Can you tell us more about the particular workload, or show performance critical code that is posing a bottleneck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just a few questions:

- 700GB compressed so how much uncompressed?
- How many files?
- What are you trying to do with these logs?  How can we divide and
  conquer?

I think you should look into MapReduce for this volume of data.

For the purposes of having an example task I'm just going to assume you have 800GB of compressed adserver event log data and you want to do something simple like count the number of unique users across that dataset.  For this quantity of data and this sort of processing multiprocessing is going to help but you'll get a lot further faster with MapReduce:  I'd look into [EMR](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) and [MrJob](http://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2010/10/mrjob-distributed-computing-for-everybody.html) or [Dumbo](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki).  Doing simple processing jobs like a user count will help validate the procedure and help you start thinking about the problem in terms of mappers and reducers.  It takes a little more time to wrap your head around more complex tasks but I think if you're going to be working with this volume of data for any real amount of time it'll be well worth the investment.

For example, counting unique users will start with a mapper that simple takes each row of adserver data and emits the userID (cookieID, IP Address, whatever we can use to differentiate between users).  You'll also have a reducer that takes these user ids as input and removes or counts duplicates.

Of course, once you resolve to give this a try there's still a fair amount of work to do.  Prepping data (splitting large files or grouping small files into blobs so that you have efficient distribution of work, storing the data uncompressed or in a compression format EMR's Hadoop flavor understands), tuning hadoop variables to work with the resources available and your algorithm, uploading data to s3, etc.

On the plus side, you should actually be able to work with 800GB of data in a matter a couple hours.

A simple mapreduce example in python:

Here's the log file format:

```
AuctionID\tUserID\tSiteID\tURL\tUserAgent\tTimestamp
```

It's just a simple tab separated value (tsv) file.

So we'll write a simple mapper to read from rows like this from stdin and write UserIDs to stdout.

```
import sys

def usercount_mapper(input):
    for line in input:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split("\t")
        user_id = parts[1]
        print "%s\t%s"%(user_id, 1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    usercount_mapper(sys.stdin)
```

And a simple implementation of the reducer to count unique userId's:

```
import sys

user_ids = {}
def usercount_reducer(input):
    for line in input:
        line = line.strip()
        user_id, count = line.split("\t")
        try:
            count = int(count)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        current_count = user_ids.get(user_id, 0)
        user_ids[user_id] = current_count + count

    for user_id, count in user_ids.iteritems():
        print "%s\t%s"%(user_id, count)

if __name__=="__main__":
    usercount_reducer(sys.stdin)
```

You can run this on a single chunk of data to test it locally by just doing:

```
$ cat mydata.tsv | map.py | sort | reduce.py > result.tsv
```

The mapreduce framework (hadoop if you use EMR) will be responsible for running multiple map and reduce tasks and sorting the data from the mappers before handing that data to the reducer.  To allow the reducers to actually do their job the MR framework will also hash the key value (the first value in your tab separated output from the mapper (UserID in this case)) and distribute mapper with the same hash to the same reducer.  This way, users with id 4 will always go to reducer 1, id 5 will go to reducer 2, etc.

If you want to build something yourself you may look directly at [Disco](http://discoproject.org/) (Disco is Python and Erlang so if you're allergic to java it may be a good choice :-)) or [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) to build out your own  mapreduce infrastructure rather than using EMR.  In the Hadoop/EMR world there are also some cool data processing platforms like [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) (SQL-like environment for describing data and mapreduce algorithms) or [Pig](http://pig.apache.org/) (like grep and awk on steroids) that may be a better fit for you than scripts like the above.

For instance, having expressed your schema in Hive you could write the following query to get unique users (assuming you'd previously defined a table users):

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.user_id FROM users;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I've tried MapReduce in Python according to a Post in IBM developworks, but the performance isn't so good. And the memory will be a problem then, for that i should put all the uncompressed file in memory before them being reduced. Eh,aftering extracting, the storage will be 20 times 700GB, that is about 10TB, I guess. Just extracting some information from the log

Comment: You tried mapreduce on your local machine?  I'd encourage you to try again with more resources on something like EC2.  You can stream the log files and decompress them on the fly.  You shouldn't have to decompress them all to disk to run this.  Of course you will need scratch space for the working files, configurations, and your output.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

From their website:

Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.    It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well.
The execution units, called tasks, are executed concurrently on a single or more worker servers using multiprocessing, Eventlet, or gevent. Tasks can execute asynchronously (in the background) or synchronously (wait until ready).

Else you can have a look at [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/)  or [Gevent](http://gevent.org/) python libraries.

Answer (score 0):

These Might solutions you might be looking for.
http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/fe55f38c64f58a9d/
http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

You can use `multiprocessing` module in python.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/

While performing operation don't `unzip` or `extract` the files.`Python` has support for accesing `7z` files without extracting.

Comment: Thanks，I was curious about how to access 7z without extracting? Should I install extra module to do this?

Comment: Yes you have to install , This site gives clear instructions how to and where to install `http://www.joachim-bauch.de/projects/pylzma/`